# How to delete an item from a database in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-vpc

I am trying to write a script with Python to delete an item from a database in my AWS DynamoDB. It needs to connect to the VPC and look for the items there, then compare it to the items saved in DynamoDB. Finally deletes all the records in DynamoDB which are not in VPC. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question really should be improved to be more clear as to what your specific problem is.  That said, the specific method to delete an item in a DyanmoDB table using Python is here: https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb.html#boto.dynamodb.layer1.Layer1.delete_item

Comment: I have a dataset in EC2 and another dataset in DynamoDB. I want to look into both datasets and delete whatever item in DynamoDB which is not in EC2 security groups.

Comment: What do you mean by "a dataset in EC2"? Where would your code be running? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I already have a script to read the items store in a database in my EC2 and make a copy of it a database in DynamoDB. 
In a situation where a user deletes an item from the database in ec2 , the item still exist in the copy version in 
DynamoDB.

Comment: I need to write another script to reads items From the DynamoDB database and see if it is available in ec2. If not delete it.
I wrote this code to get a specified item with a known primary key value
my_table = db_conn.get_table('[db-name]')        
        my_item = my_table.get_item(
  hash_key = '[primary-key-value]' 
     )

But I need a code to read a database item by item from DynamoBd so that I can compare it with my items in ec2.